# What does it take to implement authentication provider for ServiceStack with RavenDB datastore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I've been looking at the ServiceStack's SocialBootstrapAPI example app and it seems most of the wiring is done inside the AppHost class. That is the *wiring.*

Looking at this page, there are some clues and I might just start coding away but I fear I might miss some points along the way: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization

I know I have to inherit `CredentialsAuthProvider` and override `TryAuthenticate` but I guess I also have to implement IUserAuthRepository to work with RavenDB database.

So I came up with just one class, someone please tell me if this will work (if anyone has done it before):

```
public sealed class RavenDBAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider, IUserAuthRepository
```

will this be enough or is there anything else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to implement `IUserAuthRepository` which is what all the built-in Auth providers use to persist the UserAuth Info.

If you want to change the data models used i.e. use something other than [UserAuth / UserOAuthProvider POCOs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/UserAuth.cs) then you want to implement your own AuthProviders as well. CredentialsAuthProvider just allows the standard User/Password form authentication.

The existing  `IUserAuthRepository`implementations should be a good reference on how to go about implementing it:

- [MongoDBAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Contrib/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.MongoDB/MongoDBAuthRepository.cs)
- [NHibernateUserAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Contrib/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.NHibernate/NHibernateUserAuthRepository.cs)
- [RedisAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/RedisAuthRepository.cs)
- [InMemoryAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/InMemoryAuthRepository.cs)
- [OrmLiteAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs)

If you would like, we would welcome the addition to the [ServiceStack.Contrib](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Contrib) project, and we can include it in the deployment cycle of ServiceStack's NuGet packages.

Comment: thanks Demis, I'll get my hands dirty over the next couple of days;)

Comment: It looks like mythz just merged ServiceStack.Authentication.Raven and I imagine it will be available via nuget soon. :-)